# Call MVC action method from Console Client - how to setup the url

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, client, webjob

I am trying to call a method on a controller from my main project via a console from the client. Trying to send putdata through to the controller.

Here is what I tried

```
 case "6":   //PUT data (Data Controller) must already exist...
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter the ID of the song to be uploaded");
                string putdata = Console.ReadLine();

                //request for method url in WEBSITE B
                var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:61381/DataController/Put");

                var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(putdata);

                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                request.ContentLength = data.Length;

                using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
                }

                var response5 = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                var responseString = new StreamReader(response5.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

                break;
        }
```

Error is in the request, throws a null exception. Cannot find the controller, I am not sure how to point this correctly.

Comment: did u try http://localhost:61381/DataController/Put from a browser?

Comment: it does not do anything. I am unsure how to locate a Method in a controller via the browser

Comment: maybe it's better to include controller and action in yr question

Comment: Thought it would have been easier just to take a screenshot containing the location of the controller and the method name @DanielB
https://i.gyazo.com/ae3c9bfac1141cd1d4be5f5b0873390a.png

Comment: dont u need HttpPut attribute for action? u can test 
 api by https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en

Comment: I've just downloaded it but the problem is, I don't know how to locate it. Is it "http://localhost:61381/controllername/method/data-to-pass? @DanielB